# Showing div on scroll just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just like the title says! I'm having this div appear on scroll and I have the code, but I want the action to occur only once. And not happen again if I decide to close the div(it's an alert) and scroll down again. How can I achieve this?

I've read everything I could find, but since I'm a newbie, it was all too confusing for me to understand.

Anyway, here's my code so far:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        $('#alert').fadeIn();
    } 
});
```

What do I need to add to this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a flag variable to see if it's already set.  I'd use `.data` to avoid variable name conflicts.

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100 && !$(this).data("once")) {
        $('#alert').fadeIn();
        $(this).data("once", true);
        console.log("invoked once");
    } 
});
```

```css
body {
  height:700px;
}
#alert {
  bottom:70px;
  position:fixed;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, nfn neil! I'll accept your answer in 5 min because stackoverflow said so. Haha

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Variable that returns either true or false, here's an example:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var scrolled = false;
    if (y > 100 && !scrolled) {
        scrolled = true;
        $('#alert').fadeIn();
    } 
});
```